# Validating file type via magic of an AES encrypted .ts file

Tags: aes

would it be impossible to validate the file type via magic (file command for example) of an AES encrypted ts file? asking since the magic tests are looking for the sync byte (value of 0x47) each 188 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

For a well-designed block cipher like AES, its output should be indistinguishable from random noise except to someone who knows the key, so this is not possible in the general case.

The larger problem here, however, seems to be that you are trying to use the magic tests to verify file integrity without having any other protections. Confidentiality (as provided by encryption) does not guarantee integrity, and vice versa. You should use an authenticated encryption mode that handles both or find another way to create a system that provides both confidentiality and integrity.

Comment: thanks rlee827, empirically those were also my findings.